# Making auto delete process more user friendly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, auto-delete

For over a year now, there is an [auto delete process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/152859) in place that is taking care of old abandoned / dead questions and removing them. All good and I agree this should keep going to keep the place clean.

However, right now the removal is not really friendly: auto removed questions show just "**deleted**" in the bottom without ever telling who deleted it or why. More than that - it doesn't even show in the Revisions page of the question. It's as though a ghost took over the question.

My suggestion is to make good old [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) take ownership of the delete action, showing it as the one to delete (making it clear it was system process not some ghost) plus add notice like "Removed due to being ababdonded/dead question" so we won't have to deduct this ourselves.

[Example for such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9836001/revisions) (that was undeleted) - this is link to its Revisions, as you can see the auto delete is not mentioned there at all, just the undelete done by three members.

Comment: And [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9836001/timeline) currently doesn't show it either.

Comment: @Arjan timeline normally doesn't show deletions, found [this one as example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9134/revisions) - it was undeleted at February 23 but its [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9134/timeline) does not indicate anything on that date. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed by Kevin Montrose on December 3rd, 2012. Since that time, post history records, visible in each auto-deleted post's revision history, have been created to document the time of deletion and correctly attribute it to the Community user.

Nick Craver added *reasons* to these history entries on July 8th, 2013, thus allowing those able to view them to better understand what triggered the deletion.